# LDAP_add with PHP: Inconsistent return value

Tags: php, directory, ldap, openldap, loss

I am using PHP to add a list of books in an OpenLDAP Directory.
Sometimes it happens that the boolean returned returned from PHP functon ldap_add does not match the state of the entry in the directory.
Often I get true value, but the entry is not in the directory.
I tried to send over 1000 simulated entries, it is random the amount of involved entries after every cycle.
How can I perform an analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Some.code would be helpful to see what you are doing and where an issue might happen. Also information about the OpenLDAP setup might be interesting. Is more than one server involved? Multi-master or master-replica setup?

Comment: It is OpenLDAP  2.4.45. I can try to ask sysadmin for other info. I need to understand if it is possible to disable server-side cache or if it is possible to bypass cache from client-side. Maybe it is the problem, because sometimes I have inconsistent results from ldap_search. I will try to extract php code, thanks.